# QoS on 2960X does not seem to have an impact

Tags: cisco, qos, cisco-2960

We have some issues with Dect stations that have a very high requirement in regards of delay. Communication between 2 devices should not exceed 500 microseconds (0.5ms). We decided to test some different configurations with ping statistics. So our setup is like this:

```
DeviceA - - - - SwitchA - - - - SwitchB - - - - SwitchC - - - - SwitchD - - - - DeviceB
```

We did a 1h ping from DeviceA, that is a Windows 2016 Server on a ESXi, to DeviceB that is just a Windows 10 PC. First, we did a test without any QoS active, as a reference. Then, we put the ICMP traffic into DSCP18, so it has its own free queue to use. This is the policy configuration on SwitchA and SwitchD:

```
ip access-list extended QOS_ICMP_COLORING
 permit icmp host 172.16.144.35 any
 permit icmp any host 172.16.144.35

class-map match-any QOS_ICMP_COLORING
 match access-group name QOS_ICMP_COLORING

policy-map QOS
 class QOS_ICMP_COLORING
  set dscp af21

SwitchA
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/37
 description DeviceA with IP 172.16.144.35
 switchport trunk native vlan 10
 switchport mode trunk
 power inline port 2x-mode
 mls qos trust dscp
 mls qos dscp-mutation HIDE
 spanning-tree portfast trunk
 service-policy input QOS
end

SwitchD
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
 description DeviceB with IP 172.16.144.243
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 power inline port 2x-mode
 mls qos trust dscp
 mls qos dscp-mutation HIDE
 spanning-tree portfast
 service-policy input QOS
end

Example uplink interface (same on all switches)
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/47
 description uplink
 switchport trunk native vlan 10
 switchport mode trunk
 power inline port 2x-mode
 mls qos trust dscp
 mls qos dscp-mutation HIDE
end
```

Since, there is a fixed DSCP to Queue mapping on 2960X, we use a dscp-mutation map to overwrite all unwanted markings in the network, only allowing desired markings:

```
SwitchA#show mls qos maps dscp-mutation HIDE
Dscp-dscp mutation map:
HIDE:
 d1 :  d2 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  
 ---------------------------------------
  0 :    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  1 :    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 
  2 :    00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00 
  3 :    00 00 32 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  4 :    00 00 00 00 00 00 46 00 00 00 
  5 :    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  6 :    00 00 00 00
```

We did not change any DSCP to Queue maping so this remains the default on all ports which is:

```
 queue 0:  DSCP 40–47         Voice RTP
 queue 1:  DSCP 00–15         Class-default
 queue 2:  DSCP 16–31         Voice Signaling
 queue 3:  DSCP 32–39,48–63   Citrix
```

Since we do not use voice signaling (DSCP24) in this location, the ICMP traffic (DSCP18) can use the otherwise unused queue2. In the show mls qos statistics, we can see the DSCP18 markings. I verified the whole path, everything looks good so far. We use the default queue set settings.

```
SwitchA#show mls qos interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/37 statistics
GigabitEthernet1/0/37 (All statistics are in packets)

  dscp: incoming  
-------------------------------

  0 -  4 :     1066030            0            0            0            0  
  5 -  9 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 10 - 14 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 15 - 19 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 20 - 24 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 25 - 29 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 30 - 34 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 35 - 39 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 40 - 44 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 45 - 49 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 50 - 54 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 55 - 59 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 60 - 64 :           0            0            0            0  
  dscp: outgoing 
-------------------------------

  0 -  4 :     2038575            0            0            0            0  
  5 -  9 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 10 - 14 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 15 - 19 :           0            0            0        68618            0  
 20 - 24 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 25 - 29 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 30 - 34 :           0            0       679380            0            0  
 35 - 39 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 40 - 44 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 45 - 49 :           0       974219            0            0            0  
 50 - 54 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 55 - 59 :           0            0            0            0            0  
 60 - 64 :           0            0            0            0

output queues enqueued: 
 queue: threshold1 threshold2 threshold3
-----------------------------------------------
queue 0:    974219          0          0 
queue 1:   6166478       1226     544798 
queue 2:     72375          0          0 
queue 3:    679900          0          0

output queues dropped: 
queue: threshold1 threshold2 threshold3
-----------------------------------------------
queue 0:        0          0          0 
queue 1:        8          0          0 
queue 2:        0          0          0 
queue 3:        0          0          0 

SwitchA#show mls qos queue-set 1
Queueset: 1
Queue :        1     2     3     4
----------------------------------------------
buffers :     25    25    25    25
threshold1:  100   200   100   100
threshold2:  100   200   100   100
reserved :    50    50    50    50
maximum :    400   400   400   400
```

The thing that seems strange to me is, that the DSCP18 count on the mls qos statistics DSCP outgoing, do not match the output queues enqueued for queue2. But maybe this is normal. Saldy, our ping statistics haven't improved. So we changed the policy-map to set DSCP46 and activated priority-queue:

```
policy-map QOS
 class QOS_ICMP_COLORING
  set dscp ef

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
 description DeviceB with IP 172.16.144.243
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 power inline port 2x-mode
 priority-queue out
 mls qos trust dscp
 mls qos dscp-mutation HIDE
 service-policy input QOS
end
```

The service-policies have only been applied to the interfaces where the end devices are attached. The priority-queue has been enabled on all interfaces along the path (uplinks included). But this did not affect the ping statistics. This is a network with 21 switches, most of them in a star configuration. We did the test from the same server to 3 PC's simultaneously to get more reliable data. But we had the same picture everywhere. Here are the results:

```
TC0686CQ swDAI15 no QoS     TC0686CQ swDAI15 QoS (18)   TC0686CQ swDAI15 QoS (46) Priority  
More then 1ms   2872        More then 1ms   4872        More then 1ms   1870
More then 2ms   1012        More then 2ms   2080        More then 2ms   735
More then 3ms   123         More then 3ms   160         More then 3ms   449
More then 4ms   75          More then 4ms   246         More then 4ms   39
More then 5ms   64          More then 5ms   59          More then 5ms   29
Average (ms)    0.768       Average (ms)    0.935       Average (ms)    0.873
Maximum (ms)    26.5        Maximum (ms)    23          Maximum (ms)    26.3
Timeouts    0               Timeouts    0               Timeouts    0

TC0686JZ swDAI12 no QoS     TC0686JZ swDAI12 QoS (18)   TC0686JZ swDAI12 QoS (46) Priority
More then 1ms   2507        More then 1ms   2891        More then 1ms   746
More then 2ms   865         More then 2ms   1012        More then 2ms   385
More then 3ms   150         More then 3ms   894         More then 3ms   41
More then 4ms   106         More then 4ms   64          More then 4ms   19
More then 5ms   87          More then 5ms   73          More then 5ms   34
Average (ms)    0.866       Average (ms)    0.736       Average (ms)    0.679
Maximum (ms)    48.5        Maximum (ms)    59.3        Maximum (ms)    27.9
Timeouts    1               Timeouts    0               Timeouts    1

TC0868KD swDAI08 no QoS     TC0868KD swDAI08 QoS (18)   TC0868KD swDAI08 QoS (46) Priority
More then 1ms   3145        More then 1ms   1010        More then 1ms   406
More then 2ms   1095        More then 2ms   171         More then 2ms   154
More then 3ms   145         More then 3ms   134         More then 3ms   27
More then 4ms   63          More then 4ms   62          More then 4ms   11
More then 5ms   70          More then 5ms   43          More then 5ms   27
Average (ms)    0.737       Average (ms)    0.717       Average (ms)    0.703
Maximum (ms)    43.7        Maximum (ms)    40.3        Maximum (ms)    55.7
Timeouts    1               Timeouts    1               Timeouts    2
```

We always did 1 hour of testing with a ping every 50ms, thats 20 pings/second thats 72'000 pings/hour. The average is fine for us, maybe this cannot be improved any more. But what bugs me are the maximums we can't get rid of, even with priority-queue activated. Is there something we missed in our configuration? Only explanation for me is, that the delay is coming from the end devices. We cross referenced the values to see, if maybe the server was having some load, causing all the pings to be delayed at the same time, but this was not the case. We use IOS version 15.2(2)E7 on all switches. Thanks for having a look into this long post.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91763/discussion-on-question-by-mario-jost-qos-on-2960x-does-not-seem-to-have-an-impac).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already commented, QoS can only shape your traffic *in case of congestion* - it can *prioritize some traffic before other* but it can't make your network faster. The only way to reduce idle latency is in hardware - use faster devices or fewer/shorter links.

Put another way, QoS enables you to forward high-priority traffic with (ideally) idle latency *even when there is congestion*. With ample bandwidth, there's little point in QoS.

However, 500 μs shouldn't be a problem across four switches - a decent switch ranges from 2 to 5 μs across gigabit links. Add to that .5 μs per 100 m cabling (copper and fiber doesn't matter). Add 1-1.5 μs for 10GBASE-T links.

In your scenario, the most likely cause for latency is the virtual host. I've found that a Windows VM on ESXi has at least 50 μs additional latency across physical NIC, vSwitch and vNIC. You can slightly lower that by using a paravirtualized vNIC (VMXNET) instead of the virtual E1000 or such. (We're getting off-topic though.)

However, you should note that *you cannot measure latency using `ping`*. That is a common misconception, but ICMP processing often has such a low priority that `ping` show much higher figures than you really have. Therefore, the `ping`values (more or less) show an upper boundary for latency - which often isn't much help.

Instead, you should monitor the RTT values in TCP or similar parameters. For really exact values you need to use expensive equipment (or a very elaborate lab setup).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91764/discussion-on-answer-by-zac67-qos-on-2960x-does-not-seem-to-have-an-impact).